# I can't log into a Wifi network's secondary login

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

At my school, after connecting to Wifi, they require a secondary login. I tweak my computer a lot. After the summer break, I wasn't able to bring up the secondary login page. I can connect to the Wifi network, but the secondary login doesn't show up, so I can't connect to the Internet.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. I think it might be a service issue.

Comment: Did you customize your IP address or DNS server settings? They're likely assuming you'll honor the DHCP settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing I could probably fix in about 15 seconds if I sat down at your PC, but troubleshooting via Q&A message board will be cumbersome.  I can at least give you a few things to look for:

1. Make sure your dns server and IP are set to use dhcp
2. Make sure you're not set to use a proxy server
3. Make sure you're not set for only IPv6
4. Make sure you're set to allow 802.1x authentication (this may be what the login is using)

Answer (score 0):

Does your secondary login page comes up when you open a browser? try a different browser or check what address the browser shows, on some other computer that brings up the secondary login page

Comment: If browser supported secondary login, type www.google.com and see whether the login page opens